# How to get the Status of a Scenario in afterScenario hook in Gauge?

Tags: automation, getgauge

I have a question Gauge automation framework.

I am trying to get the status of the Scenario i.e., Passed or Failed in the afterScenario hook and store it using DataStore, any idea how to get that?

I use my framework in Python, but any programming language will do.

Answer (score 1):

@Sam You could check the current scenario status in `AfterScenario` hook using the `ExecutionContext` store status of that scenario in `SpecDataStore` and then access that in the `BeforeScenario` hook of later scenario. The scenario and hooks could be tagged so specific hook runs only for specific scenarios.

Example:

```py
@AfterScenario("tag_for_scenario1")
def store_status(context):
    datastore.spec["scenario_1_passed"] = context.scenario.is_failing


@BeforeScenario("tag_for_scenario2")
def check_status():
  if not datastore.spec["scenario_1_passed"]:
     raise Exception("prerequisite scenario failed")
```